# Preamble: Excluded from this document?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, business-language

How can I state that a thing is specifically excluded from a document in the preamble?

> NOTE: This document does not address the population of the data prior to running a specific batch letter report, nor does this document address the process after printing has been completed.

Doesn't seem appropriate. Your input would be welcome.

-jjj

Comment: In what respect do you find this inappropriate?

Comment: If feel that the "NOTE:" element is the equivalent of a superscript reference, and should really feel more like:

"Caution, do not expect the following to be in the document."

Comment: Batch Letter Processing currently leverages Crystal Reports to generate a batch of reports on-the-fly. 
These reports are then processed into the related member’s My Documents store on the Imaging server.
After those reports have been successfully imported, the letters are then sent to the Front Desk for printing and mailing the physical letter to the member(s) as appropriate.
NOTE: This document does not address the population of the data prior to running a specific batch letter report, nor does this document address the process after printing has been completed.
>Taken from document preamble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following may be more concise:

This document addresses neither the population of the data prior to a specific batch letter report run, nor the process once the printing is completed.

Comment: I like what you have here.

The idea is to use it as a statement for non-technical staff. Do you think there is a simpler way to put it, without seeming condescending? If you had administrative staff that were expected to read this line, would you expect them to understand right away? If that person was an intern, would you expect the same?

Comment: I've eliminated the repetition of "this document" and "address", simplified the construction and negatives. Actually, the 'warning' is pretty concise here. I don't find anything condescending. The two technical aspects are: 'population of data' and 'batch letter report run'. If they can understand these, there's nothing more complex in it, I think :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Batch Letter Processing currently leverages Crystal Reports to generate a batch of reports on-the-fly. These reports are then processed into the related member’s My Documents store on the Imaging server. After those reports have been successfully imported, the letters are then sent to the Front Desk for printing and mailing the physical letter to the member(s) as appropriate. NOTE: This document does not address the population of the data prior to running a specific batch letter report, nor does this document address the process after printing has been completed.
>
> The idea is to use it as a statement for non-technical staff.

"Inappropriate" is putting it mildly. "This document" tells its audience a whole bunch of stuff they probably don't understand and probably wouldn't care about if they did, and fails to tell them the stuff they probably want to know. Let's try translating it into English.

> HR has sent us their quarterly whine about errors and delays in the Member Reports, and we thought it might be helpful to tell you what actually happens here in IT.
>
> We do these reports in batches, because it's a Real Pain for Real Programmers (even the ignoramuses HR keeps sending us) and Real Staff to drop their Real Work and run, format, print, or package a single document thirty times a week. So every Thursday at 3:00 (give or take fifteen minutes) we tell the system to process the names that have accumulated since the last run. Approximately a quarter of a second later (it can run as high as a third of a second on a busy week) the system dumps one copy of each report in the appropriate member's folder (assuming HR has actually remembered to create it) and another copy in a folder on Doris' desktop.
>
> (Doris Collins is our senior secretary; she's got an MA in English from Vanderbilt, she's been here twice as long as anybody else, she's four times as efficient as anybody else, and makes a quarter as much. She's slated to retire in August '17, and when HR replaces her with a half-literate and wholly uneducated Business BA they'll have something real to whine about.)
>
> Doris prints out the reports (this usually takes about forty minutes because our enormously expensive state-of-the-art ultra-high-speed color printer routinely chokes every four or five pages on the cheap pulp paper Purchasing assures us is 'rated' for this use) and hands it off to the latest intern HR has 'hired' (no pay, no benefits, and it's still more than they're worth) as a favor to somebody in Upper Management. The intern rolls his eyes and abandons pestering our (more-or-less) Real Programmers and carries the printouts over to the HR Front Desk.
>
> What happens to them after that is out of our hands; we can't oversee HR's operations. And we can't oversee the data they put into the system either. We could probably help them avoid most of their errors with a better interface—if it weren't for the fact that this entire system was written in 1985 in dBase III (the programming equivalent of, say, the Latin of the Venerable Bede), and the last guy we had capable of understanding the code was bullied into early retirement by (who else) HR in the Great Cost-cutting Purge of '03.

Comment: You are a very funny person. This was just about brilliant. Your forgot to mention that after they bullied him into retirement, they begged him to come back on contract for triple pay.